# Doing Multiple Updates in Access at the same time

Tags: sql, ms-access, updates

I have very little knowledge of how access works, but I need some more efficient then what I am doing now.

I have these queries:

```
UPDATE [Receipt Audit]
SET [Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date] = #04/07/2003#
WHERE ((([Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date])=#4/7/303#));

UPDATE [Receipt Audit]
SET [Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date] = #2/27/2004#
WHERE ((([Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date])=#2/27/404#));

UPDATE [Receipt Audit]
SET [Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date] =#5/29/2003#
WHERE ((([Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date])=#5/29/303#));

UPDATE [Receipt Audit]
SET [Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date] =#8/25/2003#
WHERE ((([Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date])=#8/25/303#));

UPDATE [Receipt Audit]
SET [Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date] = #8/28/2003#
WHERE ((([Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date])=#8/28/303#));

UPDATE [Receipt Audit]
SET [Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date] = #9/29/2003#
WHERE ((([Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date])=#9/29/303#));

UPDATE [Receipt Audit]
SET [Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date] = #2/25/2004#
WHERE ((([Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date])=#2/25/404#));

UPDATE [Receipt Audit]
SET [Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date] = #3/30/2004#
WHERE ((([Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date])=#3/30/404#));

UPDATE [Receipt Audit]
SET [Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date] = #8/23/2004#
WHERE ((([Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date])=#8/23/404#));

UPDATE [Receipt Audit]
SET [Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date] = #8/25/2004#
WHERE ((([Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date])=#8/25/404#));

UPDATE [Receipt Audit]
SET [Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date] = #8/26/2004#
WHERE ((([Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date])=#8/26/404#));


UPDATE [Receipt Audit]
SET [Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date] = #8/27/2004#
WHERE ((([Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date])=#8/27/404#));

UPDATE [Receipt Audit]
SET [Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date] = #8/30/2004#
WHERE ((([Receipt Audit].[Receipt Date])=#8/30/404#));
```

The problem is I have to run them all individually. Is there a way I could combine them into one query? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
UPDATE [Receipt Audit]
SET [Receipt Date] = DateSerial(Switch(Year([Receipt Date])=303,2003,Year([Receipt Date])=404,2004,True,Year([Receipt Date])),Month([Receipt Date]),Day([Receipt Date]))
WHERE Year([Receipt Date]) IN (303,404)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Microsoft Access can't run multiple queries simultaneously. You have two approaches I can think of.

- [Write a Macro] or VBA Procedure[1](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-macro-HA010030811.aspx):

> You can create a macro to perform a specific series of actions, and
>   you can create a macro group to perform related series of actions.
>
> In Microsoft Office Access 2007, macros can be contained in macro
>   objects (sometimes called standalone macros), or they can be embedded
>   into the event properties of forms, reports, or controls. Embedded
>   macros become part of the object or control in which they are
>   embedded. Macro objects are visible in the Navigation Pane, under
>   Macros; embedded macros are not.

However, the other route may be far better.  As you won't have to be inside of Access to run the Macro.

- Write a Query Program:

This way you can write a program that will physically connect to the database; then the program can do the heavy lifting.  This will give you far more control over it as well. Then an actual programming language will be manipulating.

Not sure if those help, I actually have an example project for something similar- I'll post it to Git and edit it here for you.

Comment: That would be great! Always so helpful.

Comment: I'm trying to remember where I put the source file on our office network though; as soon as I find it I'll post it on GIT for you to see.

Answer (score 0):

The below query could be pretty easy to run against a certain year:

```
UPDATE [Receipt Audit] AS R
SET R.[Receipt Date] = 
DateSerial(
        2004,
        Month(R.[Receipt Date]),
        Day(R.[Receipt Date])
        );
WHERE Year(R.[Receipt Date]) = 404
```

Just change the where clause and year portion of `DateSerial` for each year you want to change.

Or if `Year(R.[Receipt Date]) = 404` doesn't work then try:

```
WHERE Right(R.[Receipt Date],3) = '404'
```